# Spring rest service. Invalid chunk header

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, tomcat7, spring-restcontroller

I have spring rest controller like this. The request has content-type as "application/octet-stream" and it has gz file in body. I am parsing gz body in byte[].

```
public ResponseEntity<String> test(@RequestBody byte[] request, @RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers,
            HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {}
```

For some specific requests, I am getting below exception. And response sent to client is 400.

```
    org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: I/O error while reading input message; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Invalid chunk header
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:229) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:150) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:128) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:158) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) [spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) [spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) [spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) [spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) [spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) [spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646) [servlet-api.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) [servlet-api.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat7-websocket.jar:7.0.57]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:115) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.57]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.57]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.57]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_141]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_141]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.57]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_141]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid chunk header
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedInputFilter.throwIOException(ChunkedInputFilter.java:610) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.57]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedInputFilter.doRead(ChunkedInputFilter.java:186) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.57]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractInputBuffer.doRead(AbstractInputBuffer.java:348) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.57]
        at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:422) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.57]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:290) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.57]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:390) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.57]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.readByte(InputBuffer.java:304) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.57]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:106) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.57]
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
        at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(PushbackInputStream.java:139) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver$EmptyBodyCheckingHttpInputMessage.<init>(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:324) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:189) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        ... 59 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Have you observed nothing special when looking at the HTTP requests in the network panel of your browser's developer tools?

Comment: Malformed request. Obviously not spring related.

Comment: The client is an android app. And services are spring rest services. We found that the default http client for android was doing something when device is under specific network. e.g. In India, "Jio" is telecom operator. The issue gets only for Jio network operated devices. Changing http client at device end fixed the issue. But in what case spring rest service throws this kind of exception?

Comment: I'm having the same problem as you. Were you able to figure out why that happened?

Comment: @Asym The issue is from client end. There is nothing wrong with server. Changing http client library (to Retrofit in our case(android)) did the trick. Again, this is the last thing you should do. Before that trace the network request from client and check for any anomaly in headers or url itself.

Comment: Thanks! i slept that night and in the morning the problem went away itself. I still don't know what was it.